# Get description of Id in another table in a Yii model

Tags: yii

I think I'm kinda confused, I have a model whose some of the fields where to reference their detail/s (description/s) from another table.

eg.

```
**tblCustomers**
_______________________
Name | Address | Gender
-----------------------
  A  |   A     |  M
  B  |   B     |  M
  C  |   C     |  F

**tblGender**
__________________
Code | Description
------------------
 M   |  Male
 F   | Female
```

In my view here's how it look

```
Name A
Address A
Gender M <<< wherein what I wanted is something like

Name A
Address A
Gender M - Male
```

In my model, I am currently just doing something like these:

```
public function search($_id,$_curLevel)
{
// @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->compare('Name',$this->name);
  $criteria->compare('Address',$this->address);
  $criteria->compare('Gender',$this->gender,true);
}
```

I know its pretty obvious, since the model is just looking into a single table, but I can't figure how to relate and use another table to be able to get the description from other reference tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this, is to add a relation to my model.

I am assuming you have a model setup for the gender table, and it is called Gender. I would also rename your 'gender' column in your customer table to genderID or similar. I have renamed it for my example.

Add this code to your Customer Model:

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'gender' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Gender', 'genderID'),
   );
}
```

Then once you have created this relationship, it is very easy to extract the information in your view.

You already have the model, so now the view looks like this:

```
echo $model->name;
echo $model->address;
echo $model->gender->description;
```

Note that 'gender' in the line above is referring to the 'gender' relation we created, not the column that you had named 'gender' in the description table (I renamed that to genderID).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `HAS_ONE` instead of `BELONGS_TO`

Comment: It can be. I'm fairly sure either can be used. I always use BELONGS_TO but I am not sure if there is a performance difference. I have never noticed it being bad though.

Comment: ah ok, interesting reading: [BELONGS_TO versus HAS_ONE](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/).

Comment: What if I don't rename field to genderID, what else can I do, say if this had been a product of bad design and its already a production app, is there still an alternative?

Comment: when I tried $model->gender->description, Im getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" exception.

Comment: well, you just have to give the relation a different name to the property. I was suggesting a rename of the property in genderID, but you could call the relation _gender or something like that instead.

Comment: Also do you have a model created for the gender table? It doesn't seem to be finding your gender object(model).

Comment: Yii is throwing the "Property "Customer.Description" is not defined. " exception.

Comment: Customer.Description? Well that's correct isn't it? The description should be in the Gender model. Update your question, show me the 2 names of your models, show me the relation array in Customer model, and show me where you are trying to display the description in your view.

Comment: Also show the properties of your two model, ie Customer Model: name, address, gender. Gender Model: code, description. Finally I am assuming that you have 'code' in your Gender model setup as a primary key?

Comment: Hmm... I think Im starting to get an idea of what's happening though I haven't tried it yet, do you mean I have to have 'code' in my Gender model as a primary key? What will happen if its not a primary key (just a logical one)? I mean you just know its unique but your not telling the database that it should be really checking that its unique.

Comment: I found this for you [http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4148-ar-relation-foreign-key/](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4148-ar-relation-foreign-key/). If you don't have the primary key setup, apparently you can try this: `'_gender'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Gender', '', 'on'=>'gender=code'),`. But in all honesty, assigning primary key's is the way to go.

Comment: @Cookie_J5, yes you were right, primary key is the way to go, I was a little lucky because for each model, there was an auto-increment field which basically became my foreign key, its just that my referencing model is bombarded with just series of nos. But that solve it, and having a primary key is a database fundamentals we should always keep in mind when designing our DBs.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna the gender description then you can user the relation and display $model->gender->description; as descriped in the above answer
If you wanna a custom text as you mentioned "M - Male" then you have to add a public property and fill it in the afterFind() method

```
class Customer extends CActiveRecord {

    public $_gender;

    public function afterFind() {
       $this->_gender = $this->gender . ' - ' . $this->gender->description;
       return parent::afterFind();
    }

}
```

note: that gender relation must be exist